# RSpec functional test is redirecting to the wrong place

Tags: testing, rspec, mocking, bdd, stub

I need some help guys, trying to make this test to pass but with no luck.

```
describe 'PUT posts/:id' do 

  describe 'with valid attributes' do

    let(:mock_post) { mock_model('Post', title: 'hey! iam a mock!', description: 'a sexy model', location: 'everywhere') }

    login_user

    it 'should update the object and redirect to the post' do 
      Post.stub!(:find).with(mock_post.id).and_return(mock_post)

      Post.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({"these" => "params"}).and_return(true)

      response.should redirect_to post_path(mock_post)

      put :update, id: mock_post.id, post: { these: 'params' }
    end

    it 'should have a current_user' do 
      subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
    end

  end
```

For now, I have something like the above test and getting the following error:

```
1) PostsController PUT posts/:id with valid attributes should update the object and redirect to the post
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to post_path(mock_post)
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:200:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

PostsController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource except: [:index, :show]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :tags]
  before_filter :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :suspend, :suspend_alert]

def update
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    flash[:success] = 'Cool.'
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

protected
  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Also, how should I write the test for the `render :edit` part?

Comment: `login_user` should go in a `before(:each)` block;

Don't hard-code the value of the mock_post ID. Just call it, i.e. replace `1001` with `mock_post.id`;

Make the `put` test action go after the expectations. Repeat the `put` test action for each example.

Comment: Ok. Updated the post following your instructions. the `login_user` is a `ControllerMacro` that I copied from the `Devise` [wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)).

Comment: Check `log/test.log`, it may tell you why the redirect is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec never calls the controller action. Try adding:

```
Post.any_instance.
  should_receive(:update_attributes).
  with({"these" => "params"})
put :update, :id => "1", :post => {"these" => "params"}
```

To test the two paths that result from the call to `update_attributes`, substitute the value in the expectation:

```
it "should redirect when successful" do
  Post.any_instance.
    should_receive(:update_attributes).
    with({"these" => "params"}).
    and_return(true)`
  response.should_redirect_to(post_path(@mock_post))
  put :update, :id => "1", :post => {"these" => "params"}
end

it "should render the edit page when unsuccessful" do
  Post.any_instance.
    should_receive(:update_attributes).
    with({"these" => "params"}).
    and_return(false)`
  response.should render_template("edit")
  put :update, :id => "1", :post => {"these" => "params"}
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but where did you get the @post? I don't have one.

Comment: I have updated my post. I have made some changes to the code, so it is almost working. Please take a look. Thank you.